# LinqPad shortcuts for Uppercase/Lowercase

Tags: linqpad

Are there any shortcuts for Uppercase/Lowercase in LinqPad? I have set the "Use Visual Studio shortcut keys" option to TRUE. I notice that Ctrl-U is used for "Break when exception is unhandled". Thanks!

Comment: you can see the available keyboard shortcuts from the `Help` menu -> `Keyboard/Mouse shortcuts` - unfortunately uppercase and lowercase aren't listed, so there are no keyboard shortcuts for it

Comment: I did look there before I posted this question here. I'm hoping if there is a hidden shortcut someone might know. Thanks for your comments.